# Using a StreamWriter and StreamReader results in error "Stream not readable"

Tags: c#, csv, streamreader, streamwriter

I am trying to save data to a csv file but want to ensure that the data that I am about to save isn't already pressent in the csv file. Because of this I want to read the file first and then save the data.

```
FileStream writer = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
FileStream reader = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(writer))
        {
            if (response.Datapoints.Count != 0)
            {
                foreach (var datapoint in response.Datapoints)
                {
                    sb = new StringBuilder();
                    toBeSaved = new string[] { nameSpace, metric, instanceId, datapoint.Timestamp.ToString()};

                    foreach (string str in toBeSaved)
                    {
                        if (str == toBeSaved.Last())
                        {
                            sb.Append(str);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            sb.Append(str);
                            sb.Append(",");
                        }
                    }
                    // here I get the error that the "Stream is not Readable"
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(reader))
                    {
                        if (sr.ReadLine() != sb.ToString())
                        { // only write the data if it is not already there in the file
                            sw.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This using statement will dispose the `reader`:

```
  using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(reader))
```

The disposing of the `StreamReader` will also dispose `reader`.
When you access it the next loop iteration it is disposed, hence the error message.

You can circumvent this by creating a new `FileStream` reader every loop iteration, or by reusing the `StreamReader` and disposing it after the loop.

I would use a different approach, that is likely more performant.

Unless your input file is really big, read it completely into memory at the beginning:

```
 var lines = File.ReadLines();
```

then before you write to the csv file:

```
 if(!lines.Contains(sb.ToString())
    sw.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: How can I reuse the StreamReader if that's the better option?

Comment: The file will grow as I will write more and more data to it, possibly growing to sizes in the gigabytes. Would it then still be a good idea to read the whole file into memory at the beginning?

Comment: @BlackBruceWayne if it's gigabytes, then it would not be a good idea. Unfortunately I can't tell you how to fix your code, as I think there is a conceptual problem with it in the way you try to find the duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using .Net 4.5 or later it can be set in StreamReader constructor to leave the stream open:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712952(v=vs.110).aspx

```
public StreamReader(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, bool detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, int bufferSize, bool leaveOpen)
```